git push gives error "permission to repo denied... URL returned error 403"
I am trying to use my mac for code checkins after many days. So far, I was relying on our shared Linux box (which works fine for the same user).
When I try git push, I get following error.
% git push origin "skm/build_improvements"
remote: Permission to <top folder>/xyz.git denied to myuser.
fatal: unable to access 'https://<company's github ent server>/<top folder>/xyz.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
I have referred to many threads on stackoverflow and numerous other articles.
So far I've tried following.

I'm relying on HTTP protocol. I cannot use ssh due company policy.

At the time of cloning the repo, it asked me password. I created a new fine-grained token (beta) on github and pasted that. Clone, fetch, pull worked fined.

As per some threads, I looked at git config.

Found credential.manager was using mac's keychain. Removed those entries from keychain.
Executed git config credential.manager store.
Made sure ~/.git-credential has most recent token. It's content looks like
https://<myuser>:<token>@<github server address>
Experimented by removing, adding new token to ~/.git-credential.
Compared .git-credential content against Linux box's. Tested with same content.
Tried executing git config --unset credential.manager for manual login. Did not work.


Read one thread about using github client. Installed gh, ran gh auth login. gh auth status shows successful authentication. Running git config --list shows
credential.https://<github server>.helper=
credential.https://<github server>.helper=!/usr/local/bin/gh auth git-credential

Installed latest git version (2.44.0).

Removed the cloned repo, recloned it multiple times in above steps.
I never see error during clone, fetch, pull.

For my personal token, gave all permissions there are.


I'm out of clue. Does anyone have different steps for me to try out?

What scopes did you give your token?

github is providing new way of fine grained token. I attempted giving all permissions there are.
I also tried with classic tokens, and there also I gave all scopes.

Either you don't actually have write access to that repository or your token doesn't have the necessary write permissions.  You'd need write permissions for fine-grained tokens or the repo scope for classic tokens.

That's what my suspicion was. However, I tried with giving all permissions/scopes.
As for write permission, it works fine from another box (Linux).

Found the problem. I had outdated .netrc lying around. That was taking precedence over .git-credentials.
